# How to scale graph minimum for ncurses histogram program

Tags: c, graph, histogram, ncurses

I have ncurses program that prints histogram for bandwidth usage. I would like it to scale to graph minimum instead of being always 0 (So the graph would start from minimum speed instead of zero).

The graph is basically printed like this:

```
if (value / max * lines < currentline)
    addch('*');
else
    addch(' ');
```

How can i change the calculation so it would scale the graph minimum?

Here is the full graph printing function:

```
void printgraphw(WINDOW *win, char *name,
        unsigned long *array, unsigned long max, bool siunits,
        int lines, int cols, int color) {
    int y, x;

    werase(win);

    box(win, 0, 0);
    mvwvline(win, 0, 1, '-', lines-1);
    if (name)
        mvwprintw(win, 0, cols - 5 - strlen(name), "[ %s ]",name);
    mvwprintw(win, 0, 1, "[ %s/s ]", bytestostr(max, siunits));
    mvwprintw(win, lines-1, 1, "[ %s/s ]", bytestostr(0.0, siunits));

    wattron(win, color);
    for (y = 0; y < (lines - 2); y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < (cols - 3); x++) {
            if (array[x] && max) {
                if (lines - 3 - ((double) array[x] / max * lines) < y)
                    mvwaddch(win, y + 1, x + 2, '*');
            }
        }
    }
    wattroff(win, color);

    wnoutrefresh(win);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `min` of all values in addition to `max`. Your condition will then be:

```
if ((value - min) / (max - min) * lines < currentline)
    addch('*');
else
    addch(' ');
```

(The quotient `(value - min) / (max - min)` is between 0 and 1 and requires floating-point arithmetic.)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what i was trying to achieve.